# Which Distribution Method to be used to move Redshift Data to Azure SQL Data warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, sql-data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I have a table in Redshift having datatype as text.
I want to move this Data to Azure Data Warehouse. 
Can anyone suggest what could be the best distribution method(Hash or Round Robin) for this? as the data type is text in Redshift and has big data in it

Comment: what distribution method does it have in Redshift?

Comment: Even Distribution

Comment: Redshift Even distribution = Azure DW Round Robin. Hash is if there is some known access pattern (defined by a piece of data in the row). Round Robin is good for default